# SMB connection to server fails with "The Network path was not found", SMB attempts to connect over HTTP

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, network-share, windows-10, server-message-block

Issues with one user unable to connect to any SMB shares on any Windows Servers. The user and shares are in different domains, that have a trust between the domains. The user has permission to the shares. It's working for the other users in the same office who are running the same configuration.

Running Fiddler on the client computer shows that it's attempting to connect using HTTP instead of TCP.

This occurs if I'm testing with the FQDN, server name or IP. The server responds to pings, and I'm able to open an SMB share on the client computer from the server.

### Eventviewer

In the SMBClient -> Connectivity Logs, it's filled with Event ID 30800 events, with the following content:

The server name cannot be resolved.

Error: The requested interface is not supported.

Server name: REMOTESERVER

Guidance:
The client cannot resolve the server address in DNS or WINS. This issue often manifests immediately after joining a computer to the domain, when the client's DNS registration may not yet have propagated to all DNS servers. You should also expect this event at system startup on a DNS server (such as a domain controller) that points to itself for the primary DNS. You should validate the DNS client settings on this computer using IPCONFIG /ALL and NSLOOKUP.

### Test-Netconnection

> Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 'REMOTESERVER' -port 445
>
> ##### Result:
>
> ComputerName     : REMOTESERVER
> RemoteAddress    : X
> RemotePort       : 445
> InterfaceAlias   : Local Area Connection
> SourceAddress    : X
> TcpTestSucceeded : True

I don't know where to start troubleshooting this issue.  We had one client with the same problem a couple years ago but that one we ended up just reinstalling.

Comment: And NSLookup...?

Comment: nslookup/Resolve-DNSName resolves correctly to the server in question.

Comment: Does using the IP address work? `dir \\n.n.n.n\sharename`

Comment: Nope, FQDN, IP nor servername works, exact same error message and error in event log.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

`Enabling TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper Service made everything work again. Windows Key + R > Services.msc > Find TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper and make sure it's started and set to automatic.`

It worked for me when I had the same issue.

Comment: It shouldn't be. NetBIOS hasn't been needed in over 20 years and is a security risk.

Comment: "TCP/IP Netbios Helper service helps make things work when you don't use Netbios on your network and you use SMB (file sharing, etc) connections to servers over IPv4.

It plays a part in the ability to connect to servers using \\server.corp.contoso.com or \\ipaddress. Several Active Directory functions will not work when that service is disabled and you have Netbios off in your network.

If you have Netbios off in the network card settings, Netbios data will not be sent from a computer, so you don't need to worry about that service being started."

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying the client is not in the domain, do those clients have a dns server on the network interface which can resolve to the domain where the shares are located? Maybe try to an additional dns server pointing to the domain controller of the domain where the shares are hosted (if DNS is AD integrated). Or on the dns server which they have add a conditional forwarder to server hosting the dns zones of the domain where the shares are.

Can you reach the shares over ip? `\\*.*.*.*\share` where `*.*.*.*` is the ip of the fileserver with the shares